# Is there any danger in using `-1L` instead of `-1` in R?

Tags: r, int, double, negative-number

I'm comparing and replacing (missing) values as a part of my pipeline. Missing values are marked in my `data.table` as `-9`.

Is there any danger in using `-9L` in comparing?

```
> x <- -9
> typeof(x)
[1] "double"
>
> y <- -9L
> typeof(y)
[1] "integer"
```

Example:

```
dfmelt[value == -9L, code := paste0("0", "0")]
```

versus:

```
dfmelt[value == -9, code := paste0("0", "0")]
```

Comment: If the type of `value` is integer, this doesn't matter. If it is an assigned double, it doesn't matter either. If it is a double and a result of calculations, you shouldn't be using `==` anyway (due to floating point number precision). And of course, encoding `NA` values as a number is a sign of inferior software design.

Comment: For further reading on the above comment and floating point error, [this is worth a glance](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).

Comment: @Roland Thank you, can you write your comment down as answer? And unfortunately we work alot with ASCII files here. They come along with headaches! and thanks Alistaire, I've actually read a part of that book already, maybe I should continue reading:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type of `value` is integer, this doesn't matter. If it is an assigned double, it doesn't matter either. If it is a double and a result of calculations, you shouldn't be using == anyway (due to [floating point number precision](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9508558/1412059)). And of course, encoding `NA` values as a number is a sign of inferior software design.

I suggest to convert these values to `NA` during import:

```
read.table(text = "1,2,-9", sep = ",", na.strings = "-9")
#  V1 V2 V3
#1  1  2 NA
```

Then you can use `is.na` and avoid this problem.